# PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed - ORACLE PRIVILEGES ISSUE

Tags: oracle, privileges

I am trying to implement database security as exposed in Oracle Database Security Guide and my scenario is like this:

- user OWNER create table TABLE_A;
- user OWNER create a package PKG_A wrapping business logic on TABLE_A like this:

  ```
  package body PKG_A AS
  procedure doSomeManagerStuff (pRow TABLE_A%rowtype) as 
  begin
  ... 
  end;

  procedure doSomeDataEntryStuff (pRow TABLE_A%rowtype) as 
  begin
  ...
  end;

  procedure doSomeVisitorStuff (pRow TABLE_A%rowtype) as 
  begin
  ...
  end;

  end PKG_A;
  ```

-user OWNER create n procedures each calling a single public procedure of the package :

```
procedure ManagerStuff (pRow TABLE_A%rowtype) as
begin
 pkg_a.doSomeManagerStuff (pRow);
end;

procedure DataEntryStuff (pRow TABLE_A%rowtype) as
begin
  pkg_a.doSomeDataEntryStuff (pRow);
end;

procedure VisitorStuff(pRow TABLE_A%rowtype) as
begin
  pkg_a.doSomeVisitorStuff (pRow);
end;
```

- user OWNER create roles ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_DATAENTRY, ROLE_VISITOR
- user OWNER grant **ONLY** execute on procedure for the corresponding role
- at this point in order to test the security I create different user with different role and try a script like this :

  ```
  /** CONNECTED AS USERMANAGER **/
  declare
    lRow OWNER.TABLE_A%rowtype; /* --- Which privilege I need to grant? --- */
  begin
    lRow.field1 := value;
    ...
    OWNER.ManagerStuff(lRow);
  end;
  ```

I would like to work with procedures passing a single parameter that represent the whole table row. In this way my will is to have not to modify every procedure everytime I change the table structure or the business logic applied in the package.

Any suggestion or different approach will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems OK to me. You could create synonyms so that you wouldn't have to specify owner name every time; besides, "different user" doesn't even have to know the owner, does he?

Comment: @Littlefoot : you are right ... but : "[...] When you grant object privileges on a synonym, you are really granting privileges on the underlying object [...] " About Synonyms (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views003.htm#ADMIN11806) and it is not what I want the user is able to do.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should grant privileges on a synonym - they are granted on tables & procedures. But you could create a synonym in "other user's schema", or even a public synonym (that's though, a worse idea, but it might depend on a certain situation).

Comment: @Littlefoot : I agree with what you are saying but my issue is about the parameter to be passed to the procedure and not about the way the procedure is invoked (sorry if it was not clear enough).

Comment: For `USERMANAGER` to resolve `OWNER.TABLE_A%rowtype`, it needs `SELECT` privilege on `OWNER.TABLE_A`, either directly or via a role. Note that role privileges are not valid for stored PL/SQL, but will work in anonymous blocks as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I use an answer to better expose a solution.

The comment of William Robertson is correct but I read [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/read-object-privilege-12cr1) about the SELECT privilege. So I do not want users can directly access my tables and with the READ privilege I can reference the *rowtype* in this way:

```
declare
 lRow owner.table_a%rowtype;
begin
 null;
end;
```

I read [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/oracle/pl-sql-subtypes/) and although the post is old I try this :

- I create a package without body like this:

  ```
  create or replace PACKAGE PKG_TYPES AS 

    subtype table_A_rt is table_A%rowtype;
    subtype table_B_rt is table_B%rowtype;
    subtype table_C_rt is table_C%rowtype;
    ...

  END PKG_TYPES
  ```
- `grant EXECUTE on pkg_types to ROLE_MANAGER`
- the *rowtype* can be now referenced :

  ```
  declare
   lRow asadmin.pkg_types.account_rt;
  begin
   null;
  end;
  ```

I am still working on it but it seems to meet my needs.
Any pros and cons are appreciated.